# Flutter SliverAppBar content resize on scroll down

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got some issues with the sliver app bar and it's content. I want to resize the image in the flexibleSpace when I scroll down the content of SliverList (in a code down below), to fit image the top element in a list.

Right now, I have this (holding drag position here):[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5itzJ.jpg)

And I want to come up with something like that (and bouncing back to initial expandedHeight on drag ended):[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nikns.jpg)

Tbh, I don't have any ideas on how to achieve this behavior using the sliver app bar, any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          expandedHeight: 360,
          floating: false,
          pinned: false,
          snap: false,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: false,
              title: Text('Running running'),
              background: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/excercise_3.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
        ),
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          _TopInfo(),
          _MainContent(),
        ]))
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `SliverAppBar` enable stretch property `stretch: true`, Add `BouncingScrollPhysics()` to `CustomScrollView`, also add `stretchMode: [StretchMode.zoomBackground]` in `FlexibleSpaceBar` widget as shown below;

```
  CustomScrollView(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        expandedHeight: 360,
        floating: false,
        pinned: false,
        snap: false,
        stretch: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          stretchModes: [StretchMode.zoomBackground],
          title: Text('Running running'),
          background: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/excercise_3.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
            _TopInfo(),
            _MainContent(),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: This would mostly work. However, it stops working if you have _MainContent() smaller than the remaining space, ex. just the first 2 items.

Comment: Using physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() would do the trick.